# member function pointer and callbacks

Tags: c++, function, pointers, callback, member

Hi 
I am trying to pass a callback which is a member function.  I  understand that a function pointer and a member function pointer are different and have tried to create a wrapper and use a static cast and the void pointer.  Unfortunately I am missing something as my code produces an error at compile

```
Error   16  error C2664: 'dSpaceCollide' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'int (__cdecl *)(void *,void *,dGeomID,dGeomID)' to 'dNearCallback (__cdecl *)'
```

My code.....

```
class ODEPhysics
```

header file

```
void NearCallback (void* data, dGeomID o1, dGeomID o2);
static int StaticNearCallback(void* data, void* userPtr, dGeomID o1, dGeomID o2);

.cpp file
void ODEPhysics::NearCallback (void* data, dGeomID o1, dGeomID o2){.........}

void ODEPhysics::StaticNearCallback(void* data , void* userPtr, dGeomID o1, dGeomID o2)
{
      static_cast<ODEPhysics*>(userPtr)->NearCallback( data, o1,  o2);


}

dSpaceCollide (Space, 0, &ODEPhysics::StaticNearCallback);
```

If anyone could clarify what I am doing wrong and why it would be greatly appreciated.

Fred

Comment: What is the signature of `dSpaceCollide`?

Comment: "I understand that a function pointer and a member function pointer are different and have tried [...] a static cast". Somehow, I think you don't understand. A cast is not a magic wand that makes your problems go away.

Comment: Yes, without the signature of dSpaceCollide I can only guess. Perhaps there is not userPtr argument in the function pointer accepted in the call of dSpaceCollide? or no data argument?

Comment: Why in the class you defined `static int StaticNearCallback` and later you're used it as `void ODEPhysics::StaticNearCallback` ?..

Comment: The signature for dSpaceCollide is

Comment: void dSpaceCollide (dSpaceID space,void *data, dNearCallback callback);

Comment: apologies the int is a type should read void in both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely, from what you show, that `dSpaceCollide` just wants a

```
typedef void (*dNearCallback)(void*,dGeomID,dGeomID)
```

callback, that is, a function with a single `void*` user-data pointer and the two `dGeomID`s as parameters. The `void*` is whatever data you passed to the `dSpaceCollide` then.

Assuming `dSpaceCollide` is defined something like this:

```
void dSpaceCollide(CSpace s, void* user_data, dNearCallback cb){
  // somewhere inside the code it will call your callback:
  cb(user_data, some_other, params);
  // ...
}
```

You can then change the callbacks to this:

```
void NearCallback(dGeomID o1, dGeomID o2);
static void StaticNearCallback(void* data, dGeomID o1, dGeomID o2){
  ODEPhysics* self = static_cast<ODEPhysics*>(data);
  self->NearCallback(o1, o2);
}
```

No more need for the `void* data` pointer in the member function, as that `data` is only relevant for the static callback:

```
// assuming you call this inside of your ODEPhysics class
dSpaceCollide(Space, this, &ODEPhysics::StaticNearCallback);
// pass this as user_data
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess here, and assume `typedef void dNearCallback(void *data, dGeomID o1, dGeomID o2)`. That is to say, there's no `void* userPtr` passed to your callback. The type system catches this when you try to use `StaticNearCallback`, which *does* expect a `void* userPtr`.

Underlying this problem might be a more fundamental misunderstanding. Why does your `StaticNearCallback` have *two* untyped `void*` pointers? What are you doing with `void* data` in `NearCallback`? Remember, C++ methods have a (typed) `this` pointer, so you rarely need an untyped `void* data`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/function.html) (and maybe [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html)). They can often make your life a lot easier.

Comment: They won't if you the callback expects a simple function pointer.

Comment: @Xeo. Well, yes. I was making the assumption that he was responsible  for the calling class also.